# how to get max value from more than one table

Tags: sql-server-2005

i had the tables structure like below

```
Table1
-------
Id SessionNo
1  1
2  2
3  2

Table2
-------
Id SessionNo
1  1
2  3
3  3

Table3
-------
Id SessionNo
1  1
2  3
3  4
```

from these three tables i need the output as

SessionNo
4

please give me a query for this

Comment: Is performance an issue? How many rows are there in each table? How are your tables indexed?

Comment: nearly 3000 records in each table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be (dunno if it is the best).

```
select max(SessionNo) 
from    
  ( 
     select SessionNo
     from Table1
     union all
     select SessionNo
     from Table2
     union all
     select SessionNo
     from Table3
  )
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is unnecessary when you are applying `MAX()` to the result anyway. ;)

Comment: Idd, but as a quick solution it will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MAX(maxNo)
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(SessionNo) maxNo FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(SessionNo) maxNo FROM Table2
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(SessionNo) maxNo FROM Table3
) r
```